# Flutter; How do I make a periodic timer that stops for certain condition?

Tags: loops, flutter, timer

I want to make a loop that runs every second, that stops when a bool: `isPlaying` is on false. How do I do that?

Comment: Have your timer callback check `isPlaying` before doing any work? Or make `isPlaying` a setter that automatically cancels the `Timer` when set to false?

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
   if(isPlaying == false) return;
   //do your things here
});
```

This timer works every second. If `isPlaying` is set to false. It will return and won't execute the code.